# Fast Fourier Transformation - Rounding Errors

Tags: image-processing, rounding, fft

I am transforming an image to a frequency spectrum, convolving it with a kernel, then inverse-transforming it back.

I wanted to ask how I can handle the rounding errors which occur during the transformation. Like when I transform an image, then immediately transform it back I have an average PSNR of 127. (I transform the pixels in float format between 0.0 and 1.0.)

Is it possible to calculate the errors and correct them?

Comment: To give a better answer, I'd like to ask you, why are you concerned about numerical accuracy? Is it causing problems? Or are you just measuring and seeing?

Comment: I am just concerned that too much image information gets lost, when I apply more convolution filters to an image.

Comment: Ah okay. Now by PSNR=127, do you actually mean 127 (which is 21 dB) or 127 dB? Also, what number type are you using - float, double, or something else?

Comment: No it's 127 dB.
And I'm using float. Using double would lower the performance, right?

Comment: 127 dB is plenty =). And yes, `double` would use more memory than `float`, but you'll have to benchmark to see if it is actually a problem in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: If you want less rounding error, then you need a more accurate number format. Also, you cannot calculate the error.

More accurate floating-point formats include:

- x87 80-bit extended precision (long double)
- Fixed point with BigInteger
- BigDecimal

Also, isn't a PSNR of 127 dB very good already?